# How to awk-extract the newer version number?

Tags: awk

I just want to extract the new version number `3.3.1` only once from those lines another program (gulp) is generating.

```
[14:14:54] Using gulpfile ~/code/ninja-forms-videomail/gulpfile.js 
[14:14:54] Starting 'bumpVersion'... 
[14:14:54] Bumped 3.3.0 to 3.3.1 with type: patch 
[14:14:54] Bumped 3.3.0 to 3.3.1 with type: patch 
[14:14:54] Finished 'bumpVersion' after 42 ms
```

the number after to is relevant to me. I am thinking of a regex like
`to (\d{1,}\.\d{1,}\.\d{1,})` but do not know how to implement this in awk. Ultimately it should be something like

```
$ gulp bumpVersion | awk '/to/ ????' <--- what to put here to extract that version number only once?
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution using `grep` and regex .

```
gulp bumpVersion |grep -oP -m1 'Bumped\s\d+.\d+.\d+\sto\s\K[^ ]+'
3.3.1
```

`\d` : It means a single digit.
`\d+`: it means at least one or more digit.
`\s` : It means space characters.
`\K` : To match everything on left to it but not print it.
`-m1`: It to make grep stop after printing one match.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ gulp bumpVersion | awk '!a{if(match($0,/to [0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]/)){print substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3);a=1}}'
3.3.1
```

Brief explanation,

- `match($0,/to [0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]/)`: find the matched version number after "to"
- `substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3)`: print the sub string (which is version number) started from `RSTART+3` and its length is `RLENGTH-3`
- Set `a` as the flag, if the version is found, set it to true and stop finding.

Comment: Just exit rather than set a flag and continue reading the file - `awk 'match($0,/to [0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]/){print substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3);exit}'`

Comment: It seems like a more propoer option

Comment: Regex fails when numbers have more than two digits.